# Pandas: Filling up empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two questions. First, my filling up the data in the end triggers the following error. Second, since I am not too familiar with ``pandas'', this code is probably really untypical. If you have any improvements, feel free to help make this compact and efficient.

The code is supposed to create a crosswalk between x to y. The database may contain the same x<->y relationship several time. However, it should be unique. For every X, I check if the database is actually correct: if there is more than one relation, they all match to the same y.

Beginning of the crosswalk.csv:

```
x,y
832,"6231"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
840,"6214"
842,"6111"
```

The code

```
data = pd.read_csv('data/crosswalk_short.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

xs = df.x.unique()
result = pd.DataFrame(index=xs)
result.fillna(NaN)

for x in xs:
    ys = df[df.x == x].y
    range = arange(0, len(ys.index))
    ys = ys.reindex(range)

    if (range[-1] > 0 and not isnan(ys[1]) ):
        print 'error!'

    result._ix[x] = ys[0]
```

The error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-129-4cf0c04508c4>", line 1, in <module>
    result._ix[x] = ys[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Part 1

Anything with a single underscore as the first character of a name is generally "private" which in pandas code base really means "subject to change". So, you shouldn't be using `_ix` for *anything*. Use `loc`, `iloc`, `[]` syntax, or `ix` to perform assignment and to select subsets of your data. This error happens because `_ix` is not instantiated until you call `ix` (and its value is `None` until that happens), but this implementation detail is completely irrelevant to you as a user of pandas. Use the public APIs and you usually won't get these kinds of errors.

Also, this line

```
result.fillna(NaN)
```

is a no-op because by default `fillna` returns a copy. If you to update `result` in place, do

```
result.fillna(NaN, inplace=True)
```

This API convention is fairly consistent throughout pandas. That is, for methods where it makes sense to do so, the function signatures have something like

```
object.method(..., inplace=False)
```

by default.

### Part 2

As for your second question, it looks like you want to check whether all duplicate `xs` have the same `y` value. One way to do that is:

```
df.groupby('x').filter(lambda x: x.count() > 1).groupby('x').y.nunique() == 1
```

This says:

1. groupby the `'x'` column
2. give me subsets where there's more than a single label in the groups (repeated values in `'x'`)
3. groupby our new de-single-fied `'x'` column
4. tell me whether there's more than a single unique `'y'` for each value in `'x'`

If 4. is `False` for any of the groups, that means you have x values repeated, where the y values are different.

Here's an example of this in action (I've modified your original dataset a little bit):

```
In [94]: df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('''x,y
q832,"6231"
1,"00000000"
1,"00000001"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
0,"00000000"
840,"6214"
840,"6111"'''))

In [95]: df.groupby('x').filter(lambda x: x.count() > 1).groupby('x').y.nunique() == 1
Out[95]:
x
0       True
1      False
840    False
dtype: bool
```